# Passing base class QTableWidget to the QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

In TableWidgetItem subClass im passing the TableWidget base class as a pointer because i have to update the old value to TableWidget which will push the old value in QUndoStack. i cannot pass const reference as i have to call a public function from the base class.

im code follows as

```
TableEntry::TableEntry(TableWidget *parentTable):m_pParentTable(parentTable)
```

and inside set Data

```
void TableEntry::setData(int role, const QVariant &value)
{

    if(m_pParentTable)
        m_pParentTable->updateStackOnTableCellModify(data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
    QTableWidgetItem::setData(role, value);
}
```

but what will happen to the Base class pointer inside TableEntry class when TableEntry is deleted. will the pointer m_pParentTable will become memory leak? if so how to overcome or is there any other way to pass the base class pointer.

Comment: Yes the memory pointed by `m_pParentTable` will get leaked if `TableEntry` is deleted. You need to explicitly delete `m_pParentTable` by a call `delete m_pParentTable` inside the destructor of `TableEntry`. Better use smart pointers that handle the deletion of the raw pointers - example `auto_ptr` `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` depending on your use case

Comment: thanks for the reply Vishal. correct me if im wrong.  if i delete my m_pParentTable. whole Base Widget , table will be deleted. so how i can delete it?

Comment: will smart pointers help me with it ?

Comment: What is parent class of `TableEntry`. If it is `TableWidget`, then you can directly call method `updateStackOnTableCellModify`, without passing around pointer `parentTable`.

Comment: vcp@ means m_pParentTable = qobject_cast <TableWidget *> (parent()) ? yes it is a very good way to solve this problem. thanks vcp, i will change according to ur suggestion but it will be good if i get soln for this problem in case if TableWidget is not a parent but a base class.

Comment: And why don't you use the model view programming? It easier to manage, all the undo thingy can be done on the model side.

Comment: Apin : that is my last chance as i refered this link: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq25-undo.html#choosinganapproach

Comment: Apin@ you have any reference like Undo/Redo on table.if so please provide.